# How to use a single EIP with Serverless framework?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, amazon-vpc

I have a script to deploy a serverless based project. I'm currently using `serverless-vpc-plugin` for setting up AZ, but when using the `useNatGateway` flag - it creates an EIP per zone.

I need to force all outgoing traffic to use a single EIP (I'm accessing a 3rd party provider which has an IP restriction and I need to register my IP there).

Not sure how to change my setup to use a single EIP...

```
service: test

plugins:
    - serverless-vpc-plugin

custom:
    vpcConfig:
        cidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        useNatGateway: true

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: prod
    timeout: 30
    vpc:
        securityGroupIds:
            - Ref: LambdaExecutionSecurityGroup
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
              - ec2:*
          Resource: '*'
    environment:
        DATABASE_USERNAME: ${self:service}
        DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${self:service}
        DATABASE_NAME: ${self:service}
        DATABASE_HOST:
            'Fn::GetAtt': [RDSCluster, Endpoint.Address]
        DATABASE_PORT:
            'Fn::GetAtt': [RDSCluster, Endpoint.Port]

functions:
    app:
        handler: handler.app
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /
                  method: ANY
            - http:
                  path: /{proxy+}
                  method: ANY

resources:
    Resources:
        RDSSecurityGroup:
            DependsOn: VPC
            Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
            Properties:
                GroupDescription: SecurityGroup for RDS
                VpcId:
                    Ref: VPC
                SecurityGroupIngress:
                    - IpProtocol: tcp
                      FromPort: 3306
                      ToPort: 3306
                      SourceSecurityGroupId:
                          Ref: LambdaExecutionSecurityGroup
        RDSCluster:
            Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
            Properties:
                Engine: aurora
                EngineMode: serverless
                MasterUsername: ${self:service}
                MasterUserPassword: ${self:service}
                DatabaseName: ${self:service}
                ScalingConfiguration:
                    AutoPause: false
                BackupRetentionPeriod: 30
                PreferredBackupWindow: 01:00-02:00
                PreferredMaintenanceWindow: mon:03:00-mon:04:00
                DBSubnetGroupName:
                    Ref: RDSSubnetGroup
                VpcSecurityGroupIds:
                    - 'Fn::GetAtt': RDSSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Comment: This comment does not directly answer your question but I'd leave it here in case someone else encounter the same problem.
Each NAT Gateway must have one EIP.
You can create one NAT gateway in any AZ and let all your subnets data linked to that NAT Gateway.
With serverless framework, I imagine you'll need to configure it manually ( w/o using the useNatGateway shortcut )